# Не работает роутинг angularjs на cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, маршрутизация, cordova

не работает роутинг
на телефоне файл не найден, то в веб браузере не откликается
ну или пишет `Cannot GET /путь`
если кто и делал. то скиньте исходники посмотреть
привожу код
[index.html](http://pastebin.com/Lxk0Jt2x)
[application.js](http://pastebin.com/8mb9WtDR)
[index.js](http://pastebin.com/tnCnBaPJ)
init.js - `app.initialize();`